# Substring absolute path from known folder StorageFile

Tags: c#, path, windows-runtime, storagefolder

I'm working on a WinRT app that uses a local API.

This API returns me some path that looks like this:

> C:Users\GB\Documents\MyDocs\DIVERS\fond.png

As you know, I need to use the StorageFolder and StorageFile to use the files that are in the Documents Folder.

I was wondering if there would be a good way to substitute the "known Folder" path for the path I get from the API. It would look like this:

> MyDocs\DIVERS\fond.png

I'd like to do it in a nice way, not using splitting by "Documents" because it could get me in trouble if the user name one of his sub folders Documents.

Comment: What is your use case? That will drive the best way to do this. There isn't a 1:1 mapping between a Library and a path so no completely general method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourString = @"C:Users\GB\Documents\MyDocs\DIVERS\fond.png";
string knownFolder = @"C:Users\GB\Documents\";
yourString = yourString.Replace(knownFolder, "");
YourMethod($"{knownFolder}{yourString}");
```

Keep coding!